# How to access Elastic Search installed on GCP Compute Engine instance?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-compute-engine

I have installed JDK, JRE and Elastic Search on a Google cloud compute engine instance. I am trying to access it remotely from a browser or postman or something like this.

I have also changed the `network.host` to `0.0.0.0` and have created a firewall rule in GCP console for the instance running Elastic Search.

Suppose my ephemeral External IP address is `35.237.231.xx`.

I am trying to access Elastic Search by setting the endpoint as `http://35.237.231.xx:9200/customer?pretty` using PUT.

However, I get:

> This site can't be reached, 35.237.231.xx took too long to respond

Why is this happening but locally, I can run a curl request and get a response?

Comment: Do you mean locally in the instance you can access it?

Comment: @Vincent, ended up being a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the guide at [1] that takes you step by step to have it running in no time

[1]https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-configure-gcp.html